# What does "return p ? memcpy(p, s, len) : NULL;" mean?

Tags: c, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

What does mean of "*return p ? memcpy(p, s, len) : NULL;*" in below code?
(More generally, what is the conditional operator, `a ? b : c`?)

```
char * strdup(const char * s)
{
  size_t len = 1+strlen(s);
  char *p = malloc(len);

  return p ? memcpy(p, s, len) : NULL;
}
```

Comment: Please clarify which part of that expression is confusing to you.  There is a lot happening there.

Comment: @DavidGrayson: It's in the title... and the first and only sentence in the question.  How could the OP be more clear?  Yeesh.

Comment: @EdS. maybe OP just didn't know what a ternary operator is. maybe he didn't know how you can return memcpy. it's a valid concern

Comment: We are all guessing that he doesn't know what a ternary operator is, but it's possible he is actually confused about `return`, `NULL`, or `memcpy`.  He should tell us.

Comment: My problem is about "ternary oprator" ,Thank you guys :)

Comment: @DavidGrayson: Seemed pretty likely that it was the ternary operator... but of course you could just explain the whole line.  Not like it's terribly complicated...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means execute and return `memcpy(p, s, len)`, unless `p==0`. If `p==0`, it will return `NULL`, and *not* execute `memcpy(p, s, len)`.

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C for more.

Also, to paraphrase http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html:
The memcpy() function copies len bytes from memory area p to memory area s. The memory areas must not overlap.

That is, if we have the below memory:

```
   p            s
[][1][2][3][][][4][5][6][]
```

and len == 3, then when memcpy is called we get:

```
   p            s
[][1][2][3][][][1][2][3][]
```

Finally, the value a function returns is the value it evaluates to if you then use it in an expression; if `foo()` returns 5, `print(foo());` prints 5.

Answer (score 6):

This syntax is called a ternary operator and you can think of it as of simplified if statement. `return p ? memcpy(p, s, len) : NULL;` is the same as:

```
if(p)
    return memcpy(p, s, len);
else
    return NULL;
```

`memcpy()` function returns a pointer to dest, which is a first argument of memcpy and in your case this is `p`. So, if `p` has value different than 0 (pointer is not NULL) then return that pointer. Otherwise, return NULL.

Answer (score 4):

This is a ternary operator in C.

```
p ? memcpy(p, s, len) : NULL;
```

It means that if the first condition is true ie, `p` then return the value of `memcpy(p, s, len)` else return `NULL`.

Comment: `if the first condition is true ie, "memcpy(p, s, len)" is true then return the value of "memcpy(p, s, len)"` shouldn't this be `if the first condition is true ie, "p" then return the value of "memcpy(p, s, len)"`? (Ignoring other grammar issues)

Comment: Also note the fact that only one of the last two expressions is evaluated, which has significant consequences.

Comment: @RT I missed the period after your edit to undo my downvote. If you want to, can you edit your answer so that I can undo and then edit it back?

Comment: @Jashaszun:- I like your spirit. Thanks +1